# what does the symbol ~ do in directories

Tags: c#, directory

Let's say I have this code

```
File.WriteAllText ("C:\documents~\VideoSettings.json", jsonData);
```

what does the ~ represent in the directory?

Comment: Perhaps the down-voters could explain to this new user what is wrong with their question.

Comment: Duplicate on SU: https://superuser.com/questions/211355/what-does-the-mean-in-a-file-path

Comment: It compensates for the missing `\ ` after `C:` ?

Comment: wasn't it supposed to be ~1, and is related to old 8.3 paths?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`~` is used in server controls (.aspx, .ascx, .cshtml) in the start of the path to replace path to application root, like `http://myserver.com`

An example of correct usage of `~`

```aspx
<a href="~/Documents/VideoSettings.json" runat="server">
```

Then the link  will lead to `http://myserver.com/Documents/VideoSettings.json`

Comment: I fail to see the connection to the example in the question, but apparently OP was happy with that answer.